# Split a string into an array of 36 characters in each line without breaking words

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to split a string into an array of 36 characters in each index. Also the words should not break during this split. I am using below code to split a string without breaking words but this checks the next space after 36 is reached. My requirement is if the first index reaches 36 character , then it should check the previous space in that line and move this word to next index in array .

For  example if I have a string "This is the new content for developing" This should be split into two lines as

[0]- This is the new content for

[1]-developing

Currently the below code splits this in a single line like

[0]- This is the new content for developing

```
         var count; var len=36; 
         var curr = len; var prev = 0;          
         while (data[curr]) { 
                   if (data[curr++] == ' ') { 
                        splitArr.push(data.substring(prev,curr)); 
                         prev = curr; 
                          curr += len; 
                        } 
                      } 

        splitArr.push(data.substr(prev));
```

What I can use instead of data[curr++] in if condition to get the white space before 36 characters?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would break the string into words, and add them to batches until we'd pass the max size (`36`), at which point we start a new batch.

We split the string into words with `.split()`. I use regex instead of a regular `.split(" ")` because I want to *include the spaces* when I split the string.

As we iterate through the items, we look at the last item. Would adding this string to that last item be more than 36 characters? If so, it starts a *new* item. If not, it adds it to the previous one.

To iterate and combine the items, I elected to use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const str = "This is a demonstration of how your code might work with a longer text string. ";
const charLimit = 36;

let result = str
    .split(/(\s+)/)
    .reduce((output, item) => {
      let last = output.pop() || "";                   //get the last item
      return last.length + item.length > charLimit     //would adding the current item to it exceed 36 chars?
        ? [...output, last, item]                      //Yes: start a new item
        : [...output, last + item]                     //No:  add to previous item  
    }, []);

console.log("Result:");
console.log(result);

console.log("With lengths:");
console.log(result.map(i => ({string: i, length: i.length})));

console.log("Trimmed:");
console.log(result.map(i => i.trim()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way i can think of using word boundaries

```
(?:^|\b)[\w .]{1,36}(?:\b|$)
```

```js
let str = `This is a demonstration of how your code might work with a longer text string`

let op = str.match(/(?:^|\b)[\w .]{1,36}(?:\b|$)/gi)

console.log(op)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ao2575/3/)

Comment: But this doesn't consider special characters. If a string has special characters then the word is broken there itself. Any help on this please?

Comment: There nothing mentioned about special characters in question so I didn't considered in regard. But that's easy to achieve you just change [\w .] To [\w\W]

Comment: I am trying to split a string into two parts based on some length using regex but content with space is splitted correctly whereas continous line without space is not split and it is still a single line . Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sp6zhkfa/1/  How to split the continous number string into 2 parts based on {1,48}